# I can't find Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll in a unity game folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to mod a single player unity game. I've modded other unity games before but the game I'm currently trying to mod doesn't have a Assembly-CSharp.dll file. The other games I've made mods for have this file under the manged folder but when I open this games files it only has.

1. a il2cpp_data folder
2. a Plugins folder
3. a Resources folder
4. and few random files.

If anyone has a solution for this that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

This game has been compiled with [the IL2CPP backend](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html). So all managed code was cross compiled into native C++ code. That means all code is just ordinary native code and can't easily be decompiled. Greater protection against hacking / cheating and piracy is one of the reasons why developers use the IL2CPP backend as a way to obfuscate their code.

I'm not sure what kind of solution you're looking for. The game does no longer use mono / .NET since all code is now native code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this decompiler [Il2CppDumper](https://github.com/Perfare/Il2CppDumper)

It can dump `Assembly-CSharp.dll` from `libil2cpp.so`